# What does routine HidD_FlushQueue() exactly do?

Tags: c++, windows, usb, hid

I am using the USB-Hid Class to communicate with my USB-Device in a C++ Application.
Can someone tell me, what the routine `HidD_FlushQueue()` exactly does? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I am using it to flush the input queue before sending a command. I was told to do so to guarantee the input queue is empty.

This normally works great but in some circumstances, my programm gets stuck in this funtion and does not return.
I am not using some asynchronious methods that acess the queue could block it. Is it possible, that the problem lies on the side of the USB device? Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

A HID device can send Input Reports to the host. Windows accumulates these reports in a queue. HidD_FlushQueue() removes all the reports accumulated by Windows from the queue.

I call the function at the beginning of my reading thread and I've never had a problem, although my device doesn't send reports until they're requested.